# Pass a variable to an An activity while using an Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a simple game which after a 5 second timer expires and two conditions are checked, condition one is to level up, the intent starts the same activity and I intended to increment my variable level by one every time the player met the condition which increased the game level.

The second condition starts another activity, which is the fail screen.

I didn't want a different screen for every level up increment, when I can just load the same activity and continue going through the conditions, but as the Activity starts again the level variable resets to its initialised value, the game never leaves level 1. Is there any way to pass a variable a value to an activity when starting it?

Here is the code I have for my Activity:

```
public class FirstOneActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


MediaPlayer  ourSong;
int counter;
Button add;
Thread timer;
TextView display;
TextView lvl;
int level = 1;
int time;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(FirstOneActivity.this, R.raw.click);
    counter = 0;

    add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bAdd);

    display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvDisplay);
    lvl = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.lvldisplay);




    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            //ourSong.start();
            display.setText("Your total is "+ counter);

            if(counter ==1)

            { 

                set();
                timer.start();
            }

        }
    });


     timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(time);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{


                test();


            }
        }


    };

}


public void test(){

 if(counter>= 10 && level == 1 || counter>= 15 && level == 2)
    {    
        Intent openSplash = new Intent("com.deucalion0.FIRSTONE");
        startActivity(openSplash);
        level++;
    }

     else if(counter<10 && level == 1 || counter< 15 && level == 2){

        Intent openNext = new Intent("com.deucalion0.NEXT");
        startActivity(openNext);
    }


}


public void set(){


      if(level == 1)
    {   lvl.setText("Level is "+ level);
        time = 5000;
    }

    else if (level == 2)
    {lvl.setText("Level is "+level);
        time = 5000;
    }



}


}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  To put some data in the intent, just use the [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method, like so:

```
openNext.putExtra("levelNum", 2);
```

Then in the called Activity, retrieve the bundle of extras and pull out the one you want, like this:

```
// in onCreate() method
int levelNum = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("levelNum");
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried it but couldn't get it to do what I wanted, as I just want to do level++;, where the level value will incerease automatically, I don't know if it is because the Activity called is the same Activity doing the calling.

Comment: Oh-  If your code is calling
openNext.putExtra("levelNum", level++); that won't work:  level will be incremented by the ++ AFTER the putExtra call is made.  That's how ++ works.

Comment: you should use ++level if that is how you are doing it. so that level gets incremented before it adds it to extras

Answer (score 2):

When you create the Intent this would be how to add the data:

```
Intent openNext = new Intent("com.deucalion0.NEXT");
openNext.putExtra("Level", yourLevelVariable);
startActivity(openNext);
```

Then onCreate() in the NextActivity you would get the variable by:

```
String level = getIntent().getStringExtra("Level");
```

**Edit:** There are other methods besides getStringExtra if you want an integer or...

**Edit** You could store the level in the shared preferences with a default of 1 and increment as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am trying to increment an integer value every time the intent is called, but couldn't get your example to work, the variable has to be initialised to 1 if that makes sense?
 
Thanks!